# Scheduled Recurring Crystal Reports have status "Pending" No matter what

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects, crystal-reports-server, infoview

I have a Crystal Report in SAP BusinessObjects XI v12.1.0 (also known as Crystal Reports Server 3.1 I think).

The report runs fine manually and does everything it should.

I schedule the report to run, but no matter what, the reports it spawns show a status of "Pending" in the instance manager, and don't appear to actually run (I can't see a successful run or a recorded run anywhere in the Instance Manager section of InfoView.

Thanks for any help you can give!

## Update: Exact Steps I'm trying

- Open SAP BusinessObjects Server InfoView webapp and login as Administrator
- Click Folders and browse to the report I'd like to schedule
- View the report to ensure that it outputs correctly (it does)
- Right-click the report and select "schedule".
- The "Schedule: [report name]" dialog opens
- Under the "schedule" section, I select the following:

  - **Instance Title**: Leave as the default (report's name)
  - **Recurrence**: Set as daily, every 1 days, from yesterday 5am to 10 years from now at 5am.
  - **Schedule For**: Leave as the default ("only for myself")
  - **Notification**: Not in use
  - **Database Login**: Defined in custom data source
  - **Filters**: None (there are none in the report)
  - **Format**: Plain Text (it's supposed to be)
  - **Destination**: Set to a custom location
  - **Print settings**: Default (follow crystal reports preference setting)
  - **Events**: None
  - **Scheduling Server**: First available
  - **Events**: Leave as the default (report's name)
- See that in the history, it shows a "recurring" report, and a "pending" version of the report.

### Stopping here because i found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following error in the history log:

> source file error. [CrystalEnterprise.DiskUnmanaged]: [Invalid
>   argument]

This led me to realize eventually that the *username* and *password* fields on the File Destination Screen are not for the file, but for the machine you're connecting to.

BOE / Crystal Server makes no mention of this.

Once I adjusted that, the file drop worked.